# Pjax and reloading JavaScript on a specific page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, pjax

I want to implement Pjax and Google Map in my Rails app and I have a problem with the reloading of my JavaScript codes.

My layout/application.html.erb is like this :

```
<body>
  <%= render 'shared/navbar' %>
  <%= render 'shared/flashes' %>
  <div id="pjax-container">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
  <%= render 'shared/footer' %>

  <%= javascript_include_tag "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=******************************" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js" %>

  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>

  <%= yield(:after_js) %>
</body>
```

and the file where is my map listings/index.html.erb is like this :

```
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"></div>

<% content_for(:after_js) do %>
  <%= javascript_tag do %>

    $(document).on('ready', function() {
      handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
      handler.buildMap({ internal: { id: 'map' } }, function(){
        markers = handler.addMarkers(<%= raw @markers.to_json %>);
        handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
        handler.fitMapToBounds();
      });
    })
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

@markers is an array of the marker linked to a listing. It is defined in the Listings Controller, so it's difficult to move this javascript code.

The JavaScript code of this file works just when I reload this specific page, and it does not disappear when I change of page.

So my question is :
Is it possible to call a JavaScript code, containing some ruby information, on a specific page with the Pjax system ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply load your javascript in the success function of pjax.

Comment: This doesn't really explain how to do that. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Yes actually, I did something more difficult (call the function with a link and a remote: true) but this one is better (and I have a better comprehension of pjax now ;) )

Comment: @hugohowchoong ;) yeah.. PJAX is the best plugin to show dynamic contents without loading page.. :) enjoy coding ;)

Answer (score 0):

okay i will explain more about the solution. :)

in PJAX, most of the time it doesn't load the Jquery or js which is included to the outside of the pjax funciton but in same. so we have to load that js file in the success funciton of the pjax function using

> $getScript('Your js fle');

so that when pjax fetch new page content then the plugin also loaded and included.